# How to redirect to different dashboards after login in Laravel's Spatie laravel/permissions package

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I'm new to Laravel and I'm using Laravel 5.8 to build an application. 
I'm using spatie/laravel/permissions package to handle roles and permissions of the application.

Everything is working well but I need help with redirecting different users to different dashboards when they log in.

I have four types of users i.e ADMIN, FACULTY, REGISTRAR and STUDENT. When they log in to the application, I would like each to be redirected to their own dashboard.Instead of having one uniform dashboard.

Please help!

Comment: It would definitely help if you showed your login logic. Are you using the default `Auth` logic that comes with Laravel? Or is this handled via custom logic?

Comment: @Tim Lewis - I'm using the default login that comes with Laravel

Answer (score 0):

hi you need to create a permissions for every dashboard and then in the index file ask for what sub view have permission, if you are using blade template you can do it this way

```
<div class='container'>

@if (Auth::user()->can('Admin'))
 @include('dashboards.admin')
@endif

@if (Auth::user()->can('FACULTY'))
 @include('dashboards.faculty')
@endif

@if (Auth::user()->can('REGISTRAR'))
 @include('dashboards.registrar')
@endif

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#included-authenticating

> **Path Customization**
>
> When a user is successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to the /home URI. You can customize the post-authentication redirect location by defining a `redirectTo` property on the `LoginController`, `RegisterController`, `ResetPasswordController`, and `VerificationController`.
>
> If the redirect path needs custom generation logic you may define a `redirectTo` method instead of a `redirectTo` property:
>
> ```
> protected function redirectTo()
> {
>     return '/path';
> }
> ```

It's in this `redirectTo` function you can determine which path to send the user to, based on their roles.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your routes to use different controllers for different roles:

```
Route::middleware("auth")->get("/home", function(){
    $user = \Auth::user();
    if ($user->hasRole("admin")) {
        return app()
            ->make(\App\Http\Controllers\AdminDashboardController::class)
            ->callAction("index", []);
    } else {
        return app()
            ->make(\App\Http\Controllers\UserDashboardController::class)
            ->callAction("index", []);
    }
});
```

**Note**: The previous answer I've written wasn't working because Laravel stores the routes by their URL's and doesn't care about the middleware or group, therefore the latter always overwrites the previous one.

Comment: Are you certain this works? I'm not aware of being able to overload routes like this.

Comment: I didn't use that before but since they are callbacks which are executed with clauses, it's worth trying.

Comment: Yes @ceejayoz, it didn't work, I've tested it. I've changed my answer.